# Looping through the length of a list in jinja2

Tags: html, jinja2

I'm looking to populate something similar in jinja in html.

```
for i in range(len(my_list)):

  for j in my_list:

    print(i,j)
```

I need both the i, j value as well and to not just iterate through the list.

Don't know if there is something equivalent to range in jinja2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`loop.index0`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#for) for the purpose:

```
{% for i in my_list %}
  {{loop.index0}} {{i}}
{% endfor %}
```